# CKEditor Upload Adapter Sends [object Promise] to Server

Tags: image, vue.js, upload, ckeditor5

I have been trying to implement CKEditor5 into a vuejs project and after getting all the infrastructure working, I cannot get the actual file to upload to a php server.  The code calls the server and if I return a success message and file url, it all works correctly. Here is my code:

```
    <template> 
        ...
        <ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="details.SystemText" :config="editorConfig"></ckeditor>
        ...
    </template>


    import ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
    class UploadAdapter {
        constructor(loader) {
            this.loader = loader;
        }

        upload() {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const data = new FormData();
                data.append('upload', this.loader.file);

                axios({
                    url: '/index/uploadimage',
                    method: 'post',
                    data,
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;'
                    },
                    withCredentials: false
                }).then(response => {
                    if (response.data.result == 'success') {
                        resolve({
                            default: response.data.url
                        });
                    } else {
                        reject(response.data.message);
                    }
                }).catch(response => {
                    reject ( 'Upload failed');
                });

            });
        }

        abort() {
        }
    }
    export default {
        data () {
                details: {},
                editor: ClassicEditor,
                editorConfig: {
                    extraPlugins: [ this.MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin ],
                }
        },
        methods: {
            MyCustomUploadAdapterPlugin ( editor ) {
                editor.plugins.get( 'FileRepository' ).createUploadAdapter = ( loader ) => {

                    return new UploadAdapter( loader );
                };
            },
        }
```

Clicking the image icon in the toolbar will show the file select dialogue correctly, and upon file selection will submit a post to the server.  However, the binary file is not sent, but simply:

```
Form Data

------WebKitFormBoundaryqPGA20WRKz9VvADd
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="upload"

[object Promise]
```

I have spent two days looking at all other plugins like CKFinder and others, and I seem to always get the same content being sent to the server. The line

```
data.append('upload', this.loader.file);
```

does not seem to append the actual file which is what I think it should do.

My value of this.loader is

```
loader.file
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
catch: ƒ catch()
constructor: ƒ Promise()
finally: ƒ finally()
then: ƒ then()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"
__proto__: Object
[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending"
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined
```

Tried using their cloudservice but point to my own urls and that got the upload working.

```
                editorConfig: {
                    cloudServices: {
                        tokenUrl: '/index/tokenendpoint',
                        uploadUrl: '/index/uploadimage'
                    }
                }
```

I was also able to remove all the upload adapter code.

Thank you

Comment: I was looking at their cloud service to see if that was sending properly and it was.  I just changed the cloudserver urls to my own and it worked. I posted the changes to my question.  Did not really solve why loader.file would not work for me, but in the end I got the file uploaded.

Comment: It seems that [the guide](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/upload-adapter.html) about upload adapters has some bug. Sorry for that. We're on it: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1618.

Comment: The documentation has been updated and the new version will be published on ckeditor.com/docs soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reason for your problem is that in version 11.0.0 of ckeditor5-upload plugin the API was changed, `loader.file` is now a `Promise` (see [release notes](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5-upload/releases/tag/v11.0.0)). Unfortunately the docs were not updated accordingly.

You need to adjust your upload function a little:

```
upload() {
    return this.loader.file
        .then( uploadedFile => {
            return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append( 'upload', uploadedFile );

            axios( {
                url: '/index/uploadimage',
                method: 'post',
                data,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data;'
                },
                withCredentials: false
            } ).then( response => {
                if ( response.data.result == 'success' ) {
                    resolve( {
                        default: response.data.url
                    } );
                } else {
                    reject( response.data.message );
                }
            } ).catch( response => {
                reject( 'Upload failed' );
            } );

        } );
    } );
}
```

The [docs that had this issue](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/12.0.0/framework/guides/deep-dive/upload-adapter.html) are now fixed and use promise properly. Hope this solves the problem for you!

Comment: I replaced my code with this and the upload was a binary file.  Excellent...however, there must be some other issue with my code in that the image would appear then immediately disappear.  I copied the exact example adapter code from the Docs, replacing their url with mine, and that did the trick.  I would like to know why the image was wiped out immediately after the upload, could have something to do with listener for progress, etc. Will post if I feel the urge to investigate further, but after the time I spent on this, I just want to move on.

Comment: I don't have an option to try out any code now, but from the top of my head I assume that you're not returning `url` property in the response. AFAIR response should contain url with the... well, url of file after it was uploaded (coz it could be as well renamed to avoid collision). Does that do the trick?

Answer (score 2):

Use jQuery ajax. I cannot find an equivalent using fetch or axios. The key is setting contentType: false and processData: false.

```
upload() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            const data = new FormData();
            data.append('postedFile', this.loader.file);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/index/uploadimage',
                data,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: response => {
                    resolve({
                        default: response.data.url
                    });
                },
                error: () => {
                    reject('Upload failed');
                }
            });
        });
    }
```

Comment: Using VueJS I am avoiding any use of JQuery.  Was considering SummerNote instead of CKEditor, but it to required JQuery.  Did install JQuery just to see if their ajax component worked but the "postefFile" property sent to the server is still  '[object Promise]'.

Answer (score 0):

They are working on it, it is a bug.
https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor5/issues/1618